# Get return value from a function {google apps script}

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

I have a javascript function that generates a list of folders in my drive and returns them as an array which i then stringify.  I am trying to put those folders in a table when i click a button, problem is am not quite sure how to parse the values being returned from the function in my jquery. Any help will be appreciated, here's my code

Javascript

```
   function generateFolderTree() {
      Logger.log("generateFolderTree called");
      try {

        var parentFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();

        getChildFolders(parentFolder);

      } catch (e) {

        Logger.log(e.toString());

      }

    }


    function getChildFolders(parent) {
    var i =0;

      var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
      var arrayFolder = [];

      while (childFolders.hasNext()) {

        var childFolder = childFolders.next();

       arrayFolder[i] = childFolder.getName();


        i++;

      }
       //Logger.log("Folder Name: " + arrayFolder);
       var p =  JSON.stringify(arrayFolder);
       Logger.log(p);
      return p;

    }



  show.html


 <!-- USe a templated HTML printing scriphlet to import common stylesheet. -->
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Stylesheet").getContent(); ?>
    <!-- Use a templated HTML printing scriptlet to import JavaScript. -->

    <div>
    <div class = "block" id = "dialog-elements">
    <button class = "selectFolder" id = "selectFolder" >Select a Folder</button>
    </div>
    <!-- This block is going to be hidden until the user selects a folder -->
    <div class = "block" id = "hiddenAttrib">
    <p><label for = "SelectedFolder"> Selected Folder: </label></p>
    <p><label id = "foldername"> Folder Name: </label></p>
    <p><label id = "folderid"> Folder ID: </label></p>
    </div>
    <div class = "folderTable" id = "folderTable">
    <p><label class = "showStatus" id = "dialog-status">Status: </label></p>
    <table style = "width:100%" id = "source">
    <!--<tr>
       <td> <button>Awesome</button></td>
    </tr>-->


    </table>


    </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Use a templated HTML printing scriptlet to import JavaScript. -->
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ShowJavaScript').getContent(); ?>
```

jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$("button").click(runMyFunction);
});
function runMyFunction(){
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(successCallback)
.withFailureHandler(showError)
.generateFolderTree(arrayFolders);
 $("#hiddenAttrib").hide();
 var folders = JSON.parse(arrayFolders);
 console.log(folders);
    var counter = 4;

    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<folders.length; i++){
      console.log("i = " + i);
      var row = $("<p><tr><td><button>" + folders + "</button></td></tr></p>");
      console.log("counter = " + counter);
      $("#source").append(row.html());
}
}

function showError(error) {
    console.log(error);
    window.alert('An error has occurred, please try again.');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array data is coming back as a string, you need to use the `split()` method to create an array.

```
arrayAsString.split(",");//Split string into an array. Split at comma.
```

`JSON.parse()` only needs to be used on an object.  Also, you don't need to use `JSON.stringify(arrayFolders)`.  If you want to convert an array to a string, you can use either `join()` or `toString()`.

I didn't see a separate function for the `withSuccessHandler()`.  Your code should probably look something like this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("button").click(runMyFunction);
});

function runMyFunction(){
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(successCallback)
    .withFailureHandler(showError)
    .generateFolderTree(arrayFolders);

  $("#hiddenAttrib").hide();
};

function successCallback(returnedArrayAsString) {
  console.log('returnedArrayAsString: ' + returnedArrayAsString);

  var folders = returnedArrayAsString.split(",");//Convert the array as string back to an array
  //console.log(folders);

  var i = 0,
      row;

  for (i = 0; i<folders.length; i++){
    console.log("i = " + i);

    row = "<p><tr><td><button>" + folders + "</button></td></tr></p>";

    $("#source").append(row.html());
  };
};

function showError(error) {
    console.log(error);
    window.alert('An error has occurred, please try again.');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: So i tried it just like you suggested but the returnedArrayAsString in the successCallback function returns as undefined in the console log, and thus throws an error saying cannot read property split of undefined. do yo know what could be causing this?

Comment: Your server side `.gs` function is not working.  There is no `return theArrayName;` statement in your `generateFolderTree()` function.

Comment: hey thanks, you were right, it works now a little buggy but nothing i can't fix (i think). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to stringify in this case. Your `successCallback` function is perfectly capable of receiving array from the google script function.

Comment: the returnedArrayAsString in the successCallback function returns as undefined in the console log, and thus throws an error saying cannot read property split of undefined. do yo know what could be causing this?

Comment: Cannot answer unless you show me your code. but as i said there's no need to stringify and then split. just return the array.